# The middle term of $(2x+3^y)^{12}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

> Determine the middle term in the expansion of $(2x+3^y)$ to the power of $12$.

I've tried to do it but I only know how without the $2$ that's in front .

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE! Please try to make the title of your questions as informative as possible. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 4):

HINT: The binomial theorem says that $$(a+b)^{12}=\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{12}ka^kb^{12-k}\;,$$ the middle term being the $k=6$ term, $$\binom{12}6a^6b^6\;.\tag{1}$$ You have $(2x+3^y)^{12}$, so in your case $a=2x$ and $b=3^y$; just substitute those into $(1)$ and simplify the result.